# C: Read binary data into array of structs using read(), then use qsort() to sort the data

Tags: c

*I must preface this by saying I am a complete new person to C. This is one of my first programs. This is going to be a lengthy post so bare with me. My task is as follows: I must read data from a file into an array of structs, then I must sort the data based on they key values of the data.
Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "sort.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct record
{
    unsigned int key;
    char rec[96];
}record;


int comparator(const void *a, const void *c)
{
    const struct record *elem1 = a;
    const struct record *elem2 = c;
    if (elem1->key < elem2->key)
        return -1;
    else if(elem1->key > elem2->key)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("You entered %d arguments.\n", argc);
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: ./fastsort -i [inputfile] -o [outputfile]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int option;
    int iflag;
    int oflag;
    char *outFile   = "/no/such/file";
    char *inFile   = "/no/such/file";
    while((option = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1){ //get option from the getopt() method
        switch(option){
            //For option i,o print that these are options
        case 'i':
            iflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'o': //here o is used for some file name
            outFile     = strdup(optarg);
            oflag = 1;
            break;
        case ':':
            printf("option needs a value\n");
            break;
        case '?': //used for some unknown options
            printf("unknown option: %c\n", optopt);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
    inFile = argv[2];
    //OPEN FILE TO READ
    int sz;
    struct stat sfile;
    stat(inFile, &sfile);

    //STRUCT ARRAY HERE
    char* x = (char*) malloc(sfile.st_size + 1);
    record A[100];
    //

    printf("st_size = %ld\n", sfile.st_size);
   
    int fd = open(inFile, O_RDONLY|O_EXCL);
    printf("fd = %d\n", fd);
    //IF FILE ERROR, PRINT ERROR AND EXIT
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }
    //READ CODE GOES HERE
    while (1)
    {
        int fr;
        fr = read(fd, &A, sizeof(record));
        if (fr == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("key: %u\n", A->key);
    }
    printf("KEYS PRINTED\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("UNSORTED\n");
    //TEST PRINT ARRAY DATA
    for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
    {
        printf("%u\n", A[z].key);
    }
    printf("SORTING STARTED\n");
//----------------------------------------------
    qsort(A, 100, sizeof(record), comparator);
    int b;
    for (b = 0; b < 100; b++)
    {
        printf("%u\n",A[b].key);
    }

    //CLOSE FILE AND RETURN 0
    printf("\n");
    free(x);
    printf("Freed memory\n");
    close(fd);
    printf("Closed Open File\n");
    return(0);
}
```

My current problems are as follows: When I read the data in the while loop and `printf("%u",A->key)`the key list comes out properly, however, when I then print the "array" of struct data at the bottom using z as the iterator, the data does not match the keys that were printed by any stretch of the imagination. Because of this, qsort() sorts improper data. An example of the key:record list we have to sort is:

```
key: 1804289383 rec:886 777 915 793 335 386 492 649 421 362 27 690 59 763 926 540 426 172 736 211 368 567 429 782 
key: 861021530 rec:862 123 67 135 929 802 22 58 69 167 393 456 11 42 229 373 421 919 784 537 198 324 315 370 
key: 1129566413 rec:526 91 980 956 873 862 170 996 281 305 925 84 327 336 505 846 729 313 857 124 895 582 545 814 
key: 1548233367 rec:434 364 43 750 87 808 276 178 788 584 403 651 754 399 932 60 676 368 739 12 226 586 94 539 
key: 1036140795 rec:570 434 378 467 601 97 902 317 492 652 756 301 280 286 441 865 689 444 619 440 729 31 117 97 
key: 2007905771 rec:481 675 709 927 567 856 497 353 586 965 306 683 219 624 528 871 732 829 503 19 270 368 708 715 
key: 1373226340 rec:149 796 723 618 245 846 451 921 555 379 488 764 228 841 350 193 500 34 764 124 914 987 856 743
```

Each line is 100 bytes, which is why my struct is laid out in the format it is. The key is 4 bytes and the data is 96 bytes.
*The records must stay with the keys when sorted.
Output file does not currently work as I print everything out for testing purposes

Comment: You only ever read into the first element of your array. The next iteration of the loop overwrites the previous one you read.

Comment: If the file doesn't have any headers or other meta-data in it, but is only a straight dump of `record` structures, then the number of `record` elements in it will be `sfile.st_size / sizeof(record)`. Now that you know the number of structures to read, you can create the exact size array needed, and read them *all* in a single call to `read`. No loop needed!

Comment: As for your [mcve], it's not really that *minimal*. Start simpler, even for your own sake to help with debugging issues like this. You can hard-code the path to the input file, don't need argument parsing, and don't need anything other than the actual file-reading part. Once you got the file reading part done and working, then add the sorting, and everything else one little piece at a time, building and testing at each step.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The reason that I have listed record A[100] is because the file is 100 lines long. I know the length that the array needs to be, however I don't believe I am writing to the array properly.

Comment: If your file is 100 records large (and you're certain of it) then why not read 100 records? As in `read(fd, A, sizeof A)` (assuming that `A` really is 100 elements large)? And then why bother with getting the file size and allocating for `x` which is never used (and never passed to `free`)?

Comment: @CarlNorum Thank you so much! I could not for the life of me figure this problem out! You made me realize I made a very dumb mistake and needed an iterator outside of the loop as well as reading in to &A[iterator] !

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude To be honest, reading all the documentation I could find (again, I am really new to C) I thought that it needed the size of the struct, not the size of the array it is reading to. Does the ```free(x);``` at the bottom not free the memory?

Comment: As I mentioned it's a lot of unrelated code so I missed the `free(x)` call.

Comment: The normal way production code would read records into an array is to read N records at a time until the input is exhausted. You've chosen N=1, which is fine. It might be infinitesimally slower than reading many at a time or even the whole array (which - depending on how the C runtime is implemented - can have drawbacks if the array is large), but for your first program doesn't matter at all.

Your code as written is reading every record into A[0], so each new one overwrites the previous.  You can fix it by using an index variable to select successive array elements to fill.

Comment: @Gene Thank you! Both you and Carl Norum up top found that issue. I was trouble shooting that issue for 4 hours and couldn't figure it out. I have fixed the issue and now the program does what it should. Speed fortunately isn't an issue with this.